# Server not found issue after attempting to install and then remove OpenVPN

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns, dhcp, routing

I can't access internet on Ubuntu 16.04. It shows `server not found` on Firefox and I can't access anything to install using terminal. My internet connection was working good but I tried to install openvpn using terminal and then removed it using terminal. From then this issue arose.

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP,> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 bdr 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/either 18:db:f2:4a:90:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/either e4:02:9b:48:c9:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp2s0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2405:204:6322:99a0:2c20:3623:c01a:161e/64 scope global temporary dynamic
    valid_lft 3387sec preferred_lft 3387sec
    inet6 2405:204:6322:99a0:e602:9bff:fe48:c9a2/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
    valid_lft 3387sec preferred_lft 3387sec
    inet6 fe80::e602:9bff:fe48:c9a2/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and

```
$ ping -c 10 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=44 time=98.8ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=44 time=97.9ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=44 time=96.8ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=44 time=95.7ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=44 time=93.8ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 50% packet loss, time 9119ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev/ =93.863/96.641/98.800/1.741 ms
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg -l resolvconf
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description    +++-==============-============-============-=================================
rc  resolvconf     1.78ubuntu6  all          name server information handler

$ sudo dpkg -l wpasupplicant
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/conf-files/Unknown/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad
||/Name            Version      Architecture Description 
+++-==============-============-============-================================
 ii  wpasupplicant 2.4-0ubuntu6 amd64         client support fpr WPA and WPA2
```

and `ls /etc/` is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x9ppccdH7h/plain/) which is showing no `/etc/resolv.conf` file and does not let me create it manually either.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: post the `ip addr`  and `ping -c 10 8.8.8.8` result using paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: No change... i still get "SERVER NOT FOUND"

Comment: At first everythng was fine. Nd i tried to install openvpn  using terminal nd then removed it using terminal... from then this issue arised...

Comment: those results would have helped but you can try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and then `sudo systemctl restart networking`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional information about the package you installed (and installation method--the actual command used to install) and the command(s) you used to uninstall

Comment: Commands used to install vpn - sudo apt-get install openvpn. sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome. sudo apt install resolvconf. And to uninstall same commands as above with remove in place of install.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/v5tKqcFHqS/plain/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dPcQT97wjD/plain/

Comment: Pavel sayekat.. above links are the results you asked for... nd the two commands you mentioned earliee didnt work..

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ip -4 route`, `ip -6 route`, `host google.com`, `host google.com 8.8.8.8` and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev show` as well as the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`? Please don't link to the plain text versions of Ubuntu Paste links since they require a Launchpad account, i. e. use https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/v5tKqcFHqS/ instead of https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/v5tKqcFHqS/plain/. Thanks.

Comment: @arunparavel please add the details of the above mentioned commands by David Foerster.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y4VfR7n22n/

Comment: Any solution for the issue?

Comment: @davidfoerster.. is there a solution for this issue...

Comment: The wireless connection is in unmanaged mode (from the point of view of *Network Manager*, Ubuntu's default network (auto-)management subsystem). Could you please open the *Network* section of the *Settings* applications, find and reset the wireless connection settings? There’s an [option for that in the connection details](https://i.imgur.com/QrA8e0r.png). If you’re unsure what to to, e. g. because your connection settings look very different, a screenshot may help to explain the situation.

Comment: P.S.: You can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications. The *Settings* application executable name is `unity-control-center`, `gnome-control-center`, etc. depending on your desktop environment but the *Network* section of all of them should work across DEs regardless.

Comment: @arunparavel check out the last two comments of David Forester.

Comment: @pavelsayekat. I did reset the wifi connection in network manager... nd didnt work.... what should i do now?

Comment: @arunparavel post the `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev show` again then to see if it has any different state.

Answer (score 0):

After conversation, it seems like your machine is behind a wifi-router and you are connected to network through wifi but having dns issue after installing and removing openvpn.

So to solve that, one of the ways is to edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file by

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and then add these lines in there but don't wipe anything that is previously there

```
allow-hotplug wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and press `ctrl+x` (ctrl -> control key) to save that file and then press `y` to confirm and then run `nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and add the following lines

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IN

network={
    ssid="your_wifi_network_name"
    psk="your_wifi_password"
}
```

and press `ctrl+x` (ctrl -> control key) to save that file and then press `y` to confirm and restart your networking by running

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76896/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-sayekat-server-not-found-issue-after-attempting-to).

Comment: @ThomasWard I was looking for a way to start a chat for this post but couldn't find a way but earlier the site used to suggest an option to start a chat instead of prolonging the discussion in comments.

Comment: It still does, but it doesn't move *all* comments.  (You can flag your own post for mod attention and ask for us to migrate the entire comment chain in the future next time)

Comment: @pavelsayekat.. is there a solution?

Comment: Anyone trying for a solution?

Comment: @pavelsayekat. Found any solution for this?